# Keep original Attributes on ImageButton after tampering with it on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, attributes, imagebutton

I want to enable a function that whenever you click an imagebutton, it automatically switches to a loading image which also disables it so the user cannot click multiple times until it finishes it's process.

I do the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ibtnCancel.Attributes.Add("onclick", DisableButton(ibtnCancel));
        ibtnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", DisableButton(ibtnSave));
    }


protected string DisableButton(ImageButton objImageButton)
        {
            string strAttribute = GetScript();
            strAttribute += "this.value = 'PROCESSING...';";
            strAttribute += "document.getElementById('" + objImageButton.ID + "').disabled = true;";
            strAttribute += "document.getElementById('" + objImageButton.ID + "').src = '../images/saveInactive.png';";
            strAttribute += Page.GetPostBackEventReference(objImageButton) + ";";

            return strAttribute;
        }
```

However, I have noticed that some of the attributes that were specified on the web form are no longer working, for instance:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancelar.png" CausesValidation="False" onclick="ibtnCancel_Click" />
```

CausesValidation is no longer working, so that means that if there is a validator on the form that would be triggered, it appears when I click this button despite I try to tell it not to.

How could I turn this around?, anything that I could edit on the method specified?

Answer (score 0):

Use OnClientClick property of ImageButton instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx